# Error handling in function returning another function's Promise

Tags: typescript, error-handling, es6-promise

I'm pretty new to ES6 Promises and was wondering about error handling in the following situation:

```
// Base function
private async someFunction(...): Promise<T> {
    // returns Promise<T>
}

public async anotherFunction(...): Promise<T> {
    try {
        // stuff
        return someFunction(...);
    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
}
```

`anotherFunction` returns `someFunction` with various parameters. My question is, is a try/catch here enough to handle errors thrown by `someFunction`? or should I be doing `return someFunction(...).catch(err => ...)` or is this just bad practice entirely?

Thanks

Comment: try/catch block will not be able to handle error, as error is in async execution. So you need to .catch() it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work.

```
try{
  Promise.resolve(1)
    .then(() => {
      throw new Error('111');
    });
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

And this will not work.

```
try{
  Promise.resolve(1)
    .then(() => {
      return Promise.reject('something is wrong');
    });
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

But this is working.

```
Promise.resolve(1)
  .then(() => {
    try{
      throw new Error('Something is wrong...');
    } catch (e) {
      return Promise.reject(e.message);
    }
  })
  .catch((reason) => {
    console.log(reason);
  });
```